# Mass-spring-damper model - Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm just trying to solve a single mass-spring-damper-model by this code in Mathematica:

```
NDSolveValue[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t]==-k*x[t],  x'[0]==0, x[0]==0.01}, x[t], {t,0,10}]
```

The constants m, b, k were defined in advance.
But I get an error:

```
NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0..
```

Can anyone please help.
Thank you

Comment: Could you include how you defined `m`, `b`, and `k`?

Comment: it works for me on V 12.3 using random values for `m,k,b`.  Make sure to try from clean kernel.   btw, why are using `NDSolve` for this? this is second order linear ODE with constant coefficients. It can easily be solved exactly  by hand or by using `DSolve`

Comment: Thanks. I know this can be solved by hand, it was just my first touch with Mathematica.

Comment: I have used m= 20000kg, b=100000N.s/m, k=800000 N/m which could be values of bogie of a railway car, with typical eigen frequence around 1 Hz, which is comfortable swinging for human feeling. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
m = 1;
b = 0.05;
k = 3;
sol = NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] == -k*x[t], x'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 0.01}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

but if you want to use NDSolveValue instead this would be the way to go:

```
m = 1;
b = 0.05;
k = 3;
sol = NDSolveValue[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] == -k*x[t], x'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 0.01}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfect!

Comment: Here is the final code, which I found usefull:

`(*Single mass damper system of a rail car *)
(*with 10 mm starting deflection *)
m = 40000;     (* [kg]    *)
b = 160000;   (* [N.s/m] *)
k = 1600000; (* [N/m]   *)
sol = NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t]== 0, x'[0] == 0,x[0] == 0.01}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> Full , PlotTheme -> {"Grid"}, AxesLabel->{"Time [s]", "Vertical suspension deflection [m]"}, PlotLabel->Style["Single mass damper system of a rail car", 12, Bold]]`